# Using self.id to populate other fields in Django

Tags: django, django-models, save

I'm trying to populate a field called 'identification' using the primary key 'id'. However, as you know, there is no way to know what 'id' an objects is going to be before it has been saved. Therefore, stubbornly I did this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Notifications, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    self.identification = str(self.id)
```

Amusingly, this works in console:

```
>>>new = Notifications.objects.create( # some fields to be filled )
>>>new.identification
'3' (# or whatever number)
```

but when I go to my template to retrieve this object:

```
{% for each in notifications %}
  Identification: {{ each.identification }}
{% endfor %}
```

reality strikes:

```
Identification:
```

What is happening? Why is it working in console but not in a template?. What approach do you suggest to use an auto-populated field in other fields?.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?

Comment: To implement nested comments using 1 for parent, 1.1, 1.2, etc for children, 1.1.1 for children of children, etc. It's the system that joomla uses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're not saving the changes to your database.

It works in the terminal because that particular model instance (the python object - very much temporary) has the property `identification` filled. When you access it in a view or template, the `save()` method has not been called so the property / field is blank.

To make it work, call save again after your first save. Also, it might make sense to set the id only on model creation. One extra call per initial save isn't so big of a deal in most cases.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    add = not self.pk
    super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if add:
        self.identification = str(self.id)
        kwargs['force_insert'] = False # create() uses this, which causes error.
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well, yes, I imagined that was the problem. When you say I should save again, do you mean that after using save() (without modifications), I retrieve the object to fill the identification value the way I want?.

Comment: @RobertSmith: Any way you slice it you have to save changes to your model to the database somehow. One way is to call save() again (updated post) after you've determined the auto generated ID.  I don't like the way it smells, but I don't see why it would cause a problem. This will not be your bottleneck. Probably.

Comment: @RobertSmith, I'm not sure how to get the next auto ID during an insert. I wouldn't worry about the 2 queries since it's once per save. There's probably easier bottlenecks to solve... That said let me know if you figure out how to do this with one query. I'd love to hear!

Comment: I'm going to try to find out that. If I fail to get an answer, I will submit that question here. I will let you know :-).

Comment: add = True if not self.id else False

I guess you can just write "add = not self.pk"

Comment: @bildja nice one! I like that :)