# Using self.id in other field with one query

Tags: django, save

Admittedly, this is a very similar question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905387/using-self-id-to-populate-other-fields-in-django) I asked before, however, it would be very nice to have an answer to it.

I want to create an instance by using the primary key to populate another field. Yuji Tomita suggested a solution using two queries (which by the way, it works perfectly fine) but I want to know if it's possible to accomplish that using only one query.

Yuji Tomita's solution:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    add = not self.pk
    super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if add:
        self.identification = str(self.id)
        kwargs['force_insert'] = False # create() uses this, which causes error.
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _How can I reference the auto generated ID during an SQL insert?_ might help phrase this question. Watching!

Comment: Why do you need to store "identification" separately?

Comment: @Yuji: Yes, that would be a nice restatement.

Comment: @Thomas It's a long story but suppose I want to take advantage of the auto-increment feature of Django's id field. If you are asking for a final outcome I was looking for, it's a Joomla's kind of nested comments (1, 2, ... for parents, 1.1, 1.2 for children of 1, 1.1.1, etc for children of children). Identification contains those strings.

Comment: as far as i know, shy of using raw SQL (and the hassle therein) you cannot achieve less than 2 queries for this code. If however you wish to get nested comments working easily, i suggest using [django-treebeard](https://tabo.pe/projects/django-treebeard/) to manage the heirarchy.

Comment: By the way, I didn't understand a thing Yuji said before... Does this double save() (first using it to assign an 'id' and then to add 'identification') require two hits to the database or only one?. I couldn't get an answer from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#what-happens-when-you-save.

Comment: @RobertSmith the first save() saves the object and fills out the id field from the response (db hit), the second save() re-saves the model with the changed identification field (another db hit). Basically every save(), add(), remove() or delete() or related field lookup hits the db.

Answer (score 0):

If your primary key is an automatically incrementing integer, you can calculate the next key by running `SELECT MAX(id) FROM myTable` from the db shell; or in django:

```
from django.db.models import Max
next_key = MyTable.objects.aggregate(next=Max('id'))['next']+1
```

The problem with this approach is that you have to implement row locking; otherwise another process might add to the database - taking the next ID value, which will cause *your* code to give an `IntegrityError` exception; and it doesn't solve your 'two query' challenge.

A better solution is to use non-sequential primary keys. This is usually a [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). In MySQL you can use the `UUID()` function as your primary key. This guarantees (reasonably) to not have collisions and be unique.

In Django there is no official support for UUID fields (a [patch](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4682) has been submitted), but there are [lots](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1262/) [of](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/335/) [examples](http://justcramer.com/2009/02/28/improved-uuidfield-in-django/) you can use.

If you go this route then you can generate at any point a primary key and then assign it to the model without executing a query.

Comment: This is interesting but neither solves the problem or addresses the stated use case.